# Soundcard not detected

Tags: sound, soundcard

I just reinstalled Ubuntu 12.04 and upgraded the kernel to 3.2.0.29. There is no audio--the sound card is not listed in lspci output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SiS649 Host (rev 10)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge
00:02.0 ISA bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SiS964 [MuTIOL Media IO] LPC Controller (rev 36)
00:02.5 IDE interface: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 5513 IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:03.0 USB controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f)
00:03.1 USB controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f)
00:03.2 USB controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f)
00:04.0 Ethernet controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SiS900 PCI Fast Ethernet (rev 90)
00:05.0 IDE interface: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] RAID bus controller 180 SATA/PATA  [SiS] (rev 01)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV370 5B60 [Radeon X300 (PCIE)]
01:00.1 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV370 [Radeon X300SE]
```

There are no proprietary drivers or anything on the system.

The thing is, this is the second time I installed Ubuntu 12.04, using the same LiveCD, and the first time, audio worked like a charm. I submitted a bug already, but is there anything I can do to get the OS to detect my sound card w/o reinstalling?

Comment: Did you boot the same way, or did you change boot settings with F6?

Comment: How did you update the kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the modifications I can remember (all added after the install to fix various problems):

"nomodeset" and "b43.blacklist=yes" added to the grub file
"FRAMEBUFFER=Y" added to /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf

I think I did have to check options acpi=off and nomodeset when I installed Ubuntu; the LiveCD wasn't booting in trial mode. (ETA: also possibly noapic. Brilliantly, I checked these not being entirely sure what they mean, but I was desperate)

Comment: I just used the GUI update function, it updated the kernel automatically. The installer includes 3.2.0-23, I think? Now it's 3.2.0-29. I actually don't think it's the kernel that's causing the problem, because audio was broken before the updates were installed. I was hoping the update would fix the audio issue, but it didn't change.